# The text in dialog box is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Hi I have a java program. I use Eclipse as my tool. Also I have installed Java 7 Update 51, Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 51.  My code to open the dialog box for selecting the file. It works, but the problem is the text on button or textbox  on dialog box is missing sometime. [image]
[image]

Would some one tell me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

There is my code:

```
package MyPackage;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new MainForm();

}

public MainForm(){
    super("Example");
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    // Name the JMenu & Add Items
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Open"));
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Save"));
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Quit"));

    // Add JMenu bar
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(menu);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    //setSize(600, 300);
    //setLocation(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // Menu item actions
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    if (command.equals("Quit")) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (command.equals("Open")) {
        // Open menu item action
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();     
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(MainForm.this);
        if (returnVal ==  fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            // Load file
        } else if (returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION ) {
            // Do something else
        } 
    } 


     else if (command.equals("Save")) {
        // Save menu item action
        System.out.println("Save menu item clicked");
    }
}

private JMenuItem makeMenuItem(String name) {
    JMenuItem m = new JMenuItem(name);
    m.addActionListener(this);
    return m;
}


}
```

Comment: Little side note: You are using Java 7, which can switch on strings. Your actionPerformed would look real pretty using one of those. :-)

Comment: @captainroxors I am new for java. I am not understand "switch on strings." Would you give me an example or web, so I can learn more. thanks.

Comment: What's your OS? Cannot reproduce the problem on my machine. Your code looks just fine.

Comment: Switching on strings - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: @captainroxors I use VM to create the problem which is Windows 7 with 4096 memory.

Answer (score 3):

A problem in your code is in which thread is being executed. Most Swing methods can only be executed in a very specific thread called [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Because you are not doing this correctly your application will tend to have inconsistent errors. The larger it gets the easier it is that something goes wrong.

To properly execute in the EDT you need to change your main method to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new MainForm();
        }
    });
}
```

`invokeLater` schedules the execution of the MainForm constructor to the EDT, so that the GUI initialization code is executed in the proper thread.

I don't know if this alone will solve the problem but will surely solve future non-reproducible missbehaviours. I've personally seen some threading problems other times with `JFileChooser`, there are or have been several reported bugs with the thread management of this class.

Note that this is a core rule of Swing that even the [Hello world](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java) complies.

Comment: I gave you +1 just for a good advice. But on my PC, his code works fine. So that's not a real issue.

Comment: @brano works well on my PC too, but he said that the errors occur "sometimes" so this may be the cause for his machine.

Comment: But `actionPerformed` is executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, so while it's good advice, it's not necessarily an answer...

Comment: @DSquare I added your code, but the issue is still there. I will keep your code to there for preventing some future issue. thanks.