# Eclipse WindowBuilder Glitch in Text

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm getting strange results in my Eclipse WindowBuilder whenever I try to run my GUI, the top left area has glitchy text (I don't really know what else to call this problem). I've tried searching everywhere but apparently no one else is getting this problem.

Problems with the image: Display is being displayed as Displa, 'Search' is scrambled.

Problem image:

[image: image1]

I've tried creating a new project, tried reinstalling eclipse, deleting all my eclipse metafiles, redownloading WindowBuilder, I even uninstalled Java JDK and Java from my computer and reinstalled it.

I'm running

```
Windows 7 Ultimate Service pack 1 64bit.
Java 8 Update 25 (64-bit).
Java SE Development Kit Update 25 (64-bit).
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800
```

Here is my using WindowBuilder process to give you guys an insight, as I maybe doing something wrong:
Create a new project, creating new application window under WindowBuilder. Go to design, add JTabbedPane in the center, and then add JPanel(s), apply GridBagLayout under all of my tabs and then add regardless of what element I put, the first element is always affected by this glitch and so are the tabs themselves affected.

I've tried supplied all the information I can please ask me if you want to know more to try to help me figure out what is wrong.

My layout of GridBagLayout:

[image: image1]

Other notes:
I've also noticed that even after clean and fresh installs sometimes or often whenever I add a new element to my GUI after reopening or anything I get a big error and have to spam "Reparse" button a few times before I can go back to editing.

UPDATE:
I also noticed if I type anything in the text fields it will glitch out and I won't be able to see what I'm typing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: See [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and don't forget to `pack()` the enclosing `Window`.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to threads like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203884/netbeans-swing-not-displaying-components-correctly) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491990/the-text-in-dialog-box-is-missing/22492570). Usually related to the graphics card drivers or configuration. Try updating your drivers.

Comment: Wow, I never even imagined that that could be the problem. That solved it, thank you so much DSquare, I really appreciate it. I just never suspected that not using the Nvidia High performance could create such problems. I thought integrated graphics were able to handle something as simple as Java. Anyways, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to updating this question with an answer, the solution was running Eclipse using the Nvidia Graphics card rather than Integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, got it after I downloaded and installed JavaJDK.
Not sure how to fix it other then just try to resize the window a few times, and you might be able to see what it says. Also I by browser doesn't detect my java install.

EDIT:
I found this:
[Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7)
I did what the best answer said and it worked :) And yes, indeed I have NVIDIA GeForce driver and java 8 installed (that is why).

I am from norway so the text is as well... Just try to click on what I have clicked on :)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK6wD.png